# Bootstrap Responsive NavBar Issues with Columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Please help. Below code works absolutely fine when I remove the col-lg-3 and col-lg-9 classes. With those classes on, when the viewport size reduces, the navigation bar toggle button does not work. Otherwise they do. Any ideas why the column classes create this issue?

```
body
    .container-fluid
        .container
            nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable-md.navbar-light.bg-faded.row
                button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                    span.navbar-toggler-icon
                .navbar-brand.col-lg-3
                    img(src='img/main-logo.svg' height='60')
                .collapse.navbar-collapse#navbarSupportedContent.col-lg-9.nav-fill
                    ul.navbar-nav.ul-extension
                        li.nav-item.active
                            a.nav-link(href="#") Home
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') About
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Services
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Gallery
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Contact
```

Comment: Can you just share the working snippet.

Comment: See. Basically, what I am trying to do here is that use the grid system within the NavBar, however, when I do that, the NavBar no longer is responsive. Any help on how to use grid inside the NavBar?